# Parsing elements within div using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is the html I'm trying to parse:

```
<div class="entry">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" alt="Image Title">
    <p>Here is some text</p>
    <p>Here is some more text</p>
</div>
```

I want to get the text within the `<p>`'s into one ArrayList.  I've tried using Jsoup for this.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
Elements descs = doc.getElementsByClass("entry");

for (Element desc : descs) {
    String text = desc.getElementsByTag("p").first().text();
    myArrayList.add(text);
}
```

But this doesn't work at all.  I'm quite new to Jsoup but it seems it has its limitations.  If I can get the text within `<p>` into one ArrayList using Jsoup, how can I accomplish that?  If I must use some other means to parse the html, let me know.

I'm using a `BufferedReader` to read the html file one line at a time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jsoup, but something tells me that you shouldn't create a `Document` from a single line.

Comment: As your code clearly states, you only get the `first` `p` element. So I would not claim any "limitations" within jsoup, but your code.

Comment: _Doesn't work at all_ doesn't really help to know what does happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your approach to the following:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
Elements pElems = doc.select("div.entry > p");

for (Element pElem : pElems) {
   myArrayList.add(pElem.data());
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for me after changing `doc.selected(".entry > p");` to `doc.select("div.entry > p");`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are reading the html line by line. However if you want to read the whole html use the code below:

```
String line = "<div class=\"entry\">" + 
                "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/image.jpg\" alt=\"Image Title\">" + 
                "<p>Here is some text</p>" + 
                "<p>Here is some more text</p>" + 
              "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
Elements descs = doc.getElementsByClass("entry");

List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Element desc : descs) {
    Elements paragraphs = desc.getElementsByTag("p");
    for (Element paragraph : paragraphs) {
        myArrayList.add(paragraph.text());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for`-loop:

```
Elements ps = desc.select("p");
```

([http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select(java.lang.String)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29))

Comment: @Josh that is simply not true, please check for yourself before stating something so obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
String text = doc.select("p").first().text();
```